# Got a ClassNotFoundException when trying to run a slick CustomizedCodeGenerator

Tags: playframework-2.0, slick-3.0

I am trying to implement a slick CustomizedCodeGenerator.

I put the CustomizedCodeGenerator in app/codegen package.

then I've got a **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: codegen.CustomizedCodeGenerator** after trying to run the generator in build.sbt as follows:

The build.sbt cannot find codegen.CustomizedCodeGenerator.
So, where should I put my CustomizedCodeGenerator?
or maybe I need to add an additional classpath to build.sbt?

Thank You!!

**build.sbt**

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()
slick <<= slickCodeGenTask

lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")
lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
  val outputDir = (dir / "slick").getPath
  val url = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.url")
  val jdbcDriver = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.driver")
  val slickDriver = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.driver").dropRight(1)
  val pkg = "table"
  val user = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.user")
  val password = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.password")
  toError(r.run("codegen.CustomizedCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, user, password), s.log))
  val fname = outputDir + s"/$pkg/Tables.scala"
  Seq(file(fname))
}
```

**CustomizedCodeGenerator.scala**

```
package codegen

class CustomizedCodeGenerator(val model: Model) extends SourceCodeGenerator(model) {
  // customize Scala entity name (case class, etc.)
  override def entityName = dbTableName => dbTableName
  // customize Scala table name (table class, table values, ...)
  override def tableName = dbTableName => dbTableName + "Table"  
}

object CustomizedCodeGenerator {
  def run(slickDriver: String, jdbcDriver: String, url: String, outputDir: String, pkg: String, user: Option[String], password: Option[String]): Unit = {
    val driver: JdbcProfile = Class.forName(slickDriver + "$").getField("MODULE$").get(null).asInstanceOf[JdbcProfile]
    val dbFactory = driver.api.Database
    val db = dbFactory.forURL(url, driver = jdbcDriver,
    user = user.getOrElse(null), password = password.getOrElse(null), keepAliveConnection = true)

    try {
      val m = Await.result(db.run(driver.createModel(None, false)(ExecutionContext.global).withPinnedSession), Duration.Inf)
      new CustomizedCodeGenerator(m).writeToFile(slickDriver,outputDir,pkg)
    } finally db.close
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    args.toList match {
      case slickDriver :: jdbcDriver :: url :: outputDir :: pkg :: Nil =>
        run(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, None, None)
      case slickDriver :: jdbcDriver :: url :: outputDir :: pkg :: user :: password :: Nil =>
        run(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, Some(user), Some(password))
      case _ => {
        println("""
              |Usage:
              |  SourceCodeGenerator configURI [outputDir]
              |  SourceCodeGenerator slickDriver jdbcDriver url outputDir pkg [user password]
              |
              |Options:
              |  configURI: A URL pointing to a standard database config file (a fragment is
              |    resolved as a path in the config), or just a fragment used as a path in
              |    application.conf on the class path
              |  slickDriver: Fully qualified name of Slick driver class, e.g. "slick.driver.H2Driver"
              |  jdbcDriver: Fully qualified name of jdbc driver class, e.g. "org.h2.Driver"
              |  url: JDBC URL, e.g. "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test"
              |  outputDir: Place where the package folder structure should be put
              |  pkg: Scala package the generated code should be places in
              |  user: database connection user name
              |  password: database connection password
              |
              |When using a config file, in addition to the standard config parameters from
              |slick.backend.DatabaseConfig you can set "codegen.package" and
              |"codegen.outputDir". The latter can be overridden on the command line.
               """.stripMargin.trim)
        System.exit(1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I know what's going on now, I should use sub project to build CustomizedCodeGenerator first.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (maybe easier) is: instead of
`dependencyClasspath in Compile`
use `fullClasspath in Compile`
see https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Classpaths.html

Comment: @JohanLiebhart if you accept this answer I will flag another questions as duplicate so that it would point here (unless they accept first) :)